# Ascending and Descending Number Order in java

Tags: java

I'm doing an ascending and descending order number in java and here's my code:

```
System.out.print("Enter How Many Inputs: ");
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
int arr[] = new int[num1];

for (int i = 0; i<num1; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter Value #" + (i + 1) + ":");
    arr[i] =Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
}

System.out.print("Numbers in Ascending Order:" );

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.print( " " +arr[i]);
}

System.out.println(" ");
System.out.print("Numbers in Descending Order: " );
```

Currently, the code generates the following:

```
Enter How Many Inputs: 5
Enter Value #1:3
Enter Value #2:5
Enter Value #3:6
Enter Value #4:11
Enter Value #5:2
Numbers in Ascending Order: 2 3 5 6 11 
Numbers in Descending Order:
```

So, the `Arrays.sort(arr)` call seems to work - but I'm looking for a similarly simple way to provide the descending sort, and can't find it in the documentation. Any ideas?

Comment: Reverse you ascending code would achieve descending.. :p

Comment: Why are you sorting `arr` on every iteration? You only need to sort it once.

Answer (score 7):

Three possible solutions come to my mind:

*1. Reverse the order:*

```
//convert the arr to list first
Collections.reverse(listWithNumbers);
System.out.print("Numbers in Descending Order: " + listWithNumbers);
```

*2. Iterate backwards and print it:*

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
System.out.print("Numbers in Descending Order: " );
for(int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  System.out.print( " " +arr[i]);
}
```

*3. Sort it with "oposite" comparator:*

```
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>(){
   int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
      return i2 - i1;
   }
});
// or Collections.reverseOrder(), could be used instead
System.out.print("Numbers in Descending Order: " );
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  System.out.print( " " +arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.print("enter how many:");
         int num =input.nextInt();
    int[] arr= new int [num];
    for(int b=0;b<arr.length;b++){
   System.out.print("enter no." + (b+1) +"=");
   arr[b]=input.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
        for (int k=i;k<arr.length;k++) {

        if(arr[i] > arr[k]) {

        int temp=arr[k];
        arr[k]=arr[i];
        arr[i]=temp;
        }
            }

    }
    System.out.println("******************\n output\t accending order");


    for (int i : arr){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `array` and bothering with the first question of number of wanted numbers ?

Prefer an `ArrayList` associated with a corresponding comparator:

```
List numbers = new Arraylist();
//add read numbers (int (with autoboxing if jdk>=5) or Integer directly) into it

//Initialize the associated comparator reversing order. (since Integer implements Comparable)
Comparator comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();

//Sort the list
Collections.sort(numbers,comparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make two function one for Ascending and another for Descending the next two functions work after convert array to List

```
public List<Integer> sortDescending(List<Integer> arr){
    Comparator<Integer> c = Collections.reverseOrder();
    Collections.sort(arr,c);
    return arr;
  }
```

next function

```
public List<Integer> sortAscending(List<Integer> arr){   
    Collections.sort(arr);
    return arr;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package pack2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class group {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner data= new Scanner(System.in);
    int value[]= new int[5];
    int temp=0,i=0,j=0;
    System.out.println("Enter 5 element of array");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    value[i]=data.nextInt();
     for(i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
     for(j=i;j<5;j++)
     {
      if(value[i]>value[j])
      {
       temp=value[i];
       value[i]=value[j];
       value[j]=temp;
      }
     }

     }
      System.out.println("Increasing Order:");
      for(i=0;i<5;i++)
           System.out.println(""+value[i]); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int arr[] = { 12, 13, 54, 16, 25, 8, 78 };

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array just as before, but print the elements out in reverse order, using a loop that counts down rather than counting up.

Also, move the sort out of the loop - you are currently sorting the array over and over again when you only need to sort it once.

```
                Arrays.sort(arr);
                for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                    //Arrays.sort(arr); // not here
                    System.out.print( " " +arr[i]);
                }
                for(int i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
                    //Arrays.sort(arr); // not here
                    System.out.print( " " +arr[i]);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the array in ascending order and print it backwards.

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
for(int i = arr.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    //print arr[i]
}
```

Comment: @WewDiocampo You can reward your favorite answer by pressing the green checkmark on the side of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array first, and then loop through it twice, once in both directions:

```
Arrays.sort(arr); 
System.out.print("Numbers in Ascending Order:" ); 
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
  System.out.print( " " + arr[i]); 
} 
System.out.print("Numbers in Descending Order: " ); 
for(int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){ 
  System.out.print( " " + arr[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    System.out.print( " " +arr[i]);
}
```

And move `Arrays.sort()` out of that for loop.. You are sorting the same array on each iteration..

Answer (score 0):

You could take the ascending array and output in reverse order, so replace the second for statement with:

```
for(int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    ...
}
```

If you have Apache's commons-lang on the classpath, it has a method ArrayUtils.reverse(int[]) that you can use.

By the way, you probably don't want to sort it in every cycle of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

use reverse for loop to print in descending order,

```
for (int i = ar.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Arrays.sort(ar);
    System.out.println(ar[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution
import java.util.*;
/*
Sorting three numbers

*/

import java.io.*;

public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int c = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

     Integer[] arr = {a,b,c};

    Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.reverseOrder());    
    for(int i=0;arr.length > i ; i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i]+ " ");
    }                        
                                                    
}
```

}
Example:
input 7 2 10
Output 10 7 2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I have done it in this manner (I'm new in java(also in programming))

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class SortingNumbers {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan1=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many numbers you want to sort: ");
    int a=scan1.nextInt();

    int i,j,k=0; // i and j is used in various loops.
    int num[]=new int[a];
    int great[]= new int[a];    //This array elements will be used to store "the number of being greater."  

    Scanner scan2=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ");

    for(i=0;i<a;i++)    
        num[i] = scan2.nextInt();

    for (i=0;i<a;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<a;j++) {
            if(num[i]>num[j])   //first time when executes this line, i=0 and j=0 and then i=0;j=1 and so on. each time it finishes second for loop the value of num[i] changes.
                k++;} 
    great[i]=k++;  //At the end of each for loop (second one) k++ contains the total of how many times a number is greater than the others.
    k=0;}  // And then, again k is forced to 0, so that it can collect (the total of how many times a number is greater) for another number.

    System.out.print("Ascending Order: ");
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
        for(j=0;j<a;j++)
            if(great[j]==i) System.out.print(num[j]+","); //there is a fixed value for each great[j] that is, from 0 upto number of elements(input numbers).
    System.out.print("Discending Order: ");
    for(i=0;i<=a;i++)
        for(j=0;j<a;j++)
            if(great[j]==a-i) System.out.print(+num[j]+",");
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. While the question has not been answered by an accepted answer, it has been asked in 2012 and has received several answers including a very comprehensive one from @jiri-kremser. If you do answer such a question, you should also note why. In other words, what extra information does your answer provide. For example, a faster, more elegant, shorter code, etc.